# How do you hide carriage return and space markings in Xcode 12.1?

Tags: xcode, xcode12

I'm new to XCode (12). My source code editor is showing line numbers, periods marking every space and carriage returns, all displayed in light grey. I can switch off the line numbers in Preferences > TextEditing > Display. Why am I seeing markings for periods and CRs though? How do you get rid of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose Editor > Invisibles to toggle showing and hiding the invisible characters. You must select a source code file for the Invisibles menu item to appear in the Editor menu.